# How do I compare two lists of arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, byte

I have the following code:

```
List<byte[]> list1 = new List<byte[]>();
list1.Add(new byte[] { 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 });

List<byte[]> list2 = new List<byte[]>();
list2.Add(new byte[] { 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 });
list2.Add(new byte[] { 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x42, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 }); // this array

IEnumerable<byte[]> list3 = list2.Except(list1);
```

I want list3 to only contain the byte[] arrays that are in list2 but not in list1 (the one marked "this array"), but instead it just returns all of list2. So then I tried the following:

```
List<byte[]> list3 = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (byte[] array in list2)
    if (!list1.Contains(array))
        list3.Add(array);
```

but this got me the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `Except` and `Contains` invokes the object's `Equals` method. For arrays, however, `Equals` simply performs a reference equality check. To compare the contents, use the `SequenceEqual` extension method.

You'll have to change your check in your loop:

```
List<byte[]> list3 = new List<byte[]>();
foreach (byte[] array in list2)
    if (!list1.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(array)))
        list3.Add(array);
```

Comment: I suspected it would be something sort of like this, but could not find any simply way of doing it right without a looping through every byte in every array. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your lists contain only one element. Every one of them contains a byte array, and these byte arrays are different from each other, that's why the `Except` and your implementation return the same result.

I'm not a c# expert, but you could try to define the following lists:

```
List<byte> list1 = new List<byte>();
```

Answer (score 0):

use Equals function. Suppose `cont_stream` is a byte array then

```
bool b = cont_stream[1].Equals(cont_stream[2]);
```